# reloading page give me error 401 using spring security angular and rest API

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I have a relatively simple setup using Spring Boot, Spring Security and an angular client.
So i'm using an rest api to show the database on the client like a database website

so for now the login is working and when i'm log i can everything without probleme. but when i'm reloading the page i lost the authorization to the rest api i can't receive the information anymore with an error 401.

this is after the login process

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/mindnessBdd/api/v1/films
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request header
GET /mindnessBdd/api/v1/films HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Authorization: Basic bWluZG5lc3M6QFJhcGhhNzY2MjAh
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:4200/films
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

Responce header
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2020 09:32:31 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

and after reloading

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/mindnessBdd/api/v1/films
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2020 09:37:25 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Request Header
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Basic dW5kZWZpbmVkOnVuZGVmaW5lZA==
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/films
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
```

don't know if it can help but this is my auth config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().formLogin().disable();;

    }
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge((long) 3600);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

I assume that my lack of understanding of Spring Security is at fault here, can anyone see what I've done wrong?

thanks in advance !

** edit 
login component :

```
Skip to content
Search or jump to…

Pull requests
Issues
Marketplace
Explore

@mindness 
mindness
/
WebAppFront
1
00
 Code Issues 0 Pull requests 0 Actions Projects 0 Wiki Security Insights Settings
WebAppFront/src/app/login/login.component.ts / 
 raphael lefrancois login / auth / logout
c3fe322 4 days ago
Executable File  39 lines (33 sloc)  1 KB

Code navigation is available!
Navigate your code with ease. Click on function and method calls to jump to their definitions or references in the same repository. Learn more

You're using code navigation to jump to definitions or references.
Learn more or give us feedback
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string;
  password: string;
  errorMessage = 'Invalid Credentials';
  successMessage: string;
  invalidLogin = false;
  loginSuccess = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handleLogin() {
    this.authenticationService.authenticationService(this.username, this.password).subscribe((result) => {
      this.invalidLogin = false;
      this.loginSuccess = true;
      this.successMessage = 'Login Successful.';
      this.router.navigate(['/films']);
    }, () => {
      this.invalidLogin = true;
      this.loginSuccess = false;
    });
  }

}
```

authservice

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  // BASE_PATH: 'http://localhost:8080'
  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser'

  public username: string;
  public password: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  authenticationService(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/mindnessBdd/api/v1/basicauth`,
      { headers: { authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password) } }).pipe(map((res) => {
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      this.registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password);
    }));
  }

  createBasicAuthToken(username: string, password: string) {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
  }

  registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username);
  }

  logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    this.username = null;
    this.password = null;
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    const user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) { return false; }
    return true;
  }

  getLoggedInUserName() {
    const user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) { return ''; }
    return user;
  }
}
```

http interceptor

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn() && req.url.indexOf('basicauth') === -1) {
      const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Basic ${window.btoa(this.authenticationService.username + ':' + this.authenticationService.password)}`
        })
      });
      return next.handle(authReq);
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a very interesting question.

if you exam closely into the two request headers (the one after login, and the one after reload), you will find the cause.

the one after login has the Authorization encoded by Base64 as:

```
Authorization: Basic bWluZG5lc3M6QFJhcGhhNzY2MjAh
```

the one after reload is:

```
Authorization: Basic dW5kZWZpbmVkOnVuZGVmaW5lZA==
```

now if you decode the second authorization to plain text, it is:

```
undefined:undefined
```

And that's the reason you got 401, as undefined undefined is not a valid user and password.

And I guess that you got user name and password from your javascript variable, which is undefined when you reload your page...

---

update:
after reading your frontend code, it seems you saved the user name into the session storage, and when you reload the page, it assumes the user is logged in as it finds the username in the session storage. so it tries to send the token again, however the user name and password in the authentication service is not set. You can save username and token into the session storage (cookie). And when reload, it can get the token from storage, instead. And to make it safe, set the HttpOnly flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't understang why before implementing spring security i don't have this reloding problem and i don't change the system to authenticate to the rest api do u have any advice to fix that ?

Comment: Before you introducing Spring security into your app, you  didn’t  have authentication, even no user name and password can access the api. Now you have Spring security, it checks user name and password when you call the api, but when you reload it didn’t provide user name and password, and you got 401 error. Can you also share your ui code of login in your question? So we can advise how to fix?

Comment: i added everything i use to log if you see why it's not working :/

Comment: Hi Mindness, you saved the user name into the session storage, and when you reload the page, it checks the user is logged in so it tries to send the token again, however the user name and password in the authentication service is not set. You can save username and token into the session storage. And when reload, it can get the token from storage, instead

Comment: Hey bob thanks a lot for you answer it work now it in term of security it look like kinda bad no ? i added username and password in session storage so i can get back the token not sure if it really safe to do it like this

Comment: i am glad that it works now. It is a good question that how to store the username and password in session storage. the short answer is: No... it is vulnerable to XSS hack. A better way is to store the token in the cookie, and with HttpOnly cookie flag, the token is not accessible through JavaScript. here is a link you can read: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage